# why i have an empty value in urlrewriting

Tags: php, .htaccess

i created a function to change my url automatically, but when i click in the link, the url changed but i didn't have any results.

This is my function :

```
$rewrite = 'yes';
function get_info_link($id){
    global $rewrite;
    if ($rewrite=='yes') {
        $link = 'person/'.$id.'.html';
    } else {
        $link = 'information.php?id='.$id; 
    }
    return $link;
}
```

and this is the link when i called the function

```
<th>
    <a href="<?php echo get_info_link($resultat['id'])?>">
        Voir tous les infos
    </a>
</th>
```

in the. htaccess file I used this rule

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^(person)/([0-9]+)\.html$ information.php?id=$1 [L]
```

Comment: Please define no result... What is `print_r($_GET)`

Comment: Array ( [id] => person )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your rewrite rule, you take the first captured expression, you are taking the "person" string, and not the number after.

try this:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^(person)/([0-9]+)\.html$ information.php?id=$2 [L]
```

or this:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^person/([0-9]+)\.html$ information.php?id=$1 [L]
```

Both do the same, but i dont know if you want to capture the "person" string or not.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is the Rule:

```
RewriteRule ^(person)/([0-9]+)\.html$ information.php?id=$1
```

You beginn counting with 1 not with zero here. So this would be right:

```
RewriteRule ^(person)/([0-9]+)\.html$ information.php?id=$2
```

Alternative, you can do it better:

```
RewriteRule ^person/([0-9]+)\.html$ information.php?id=$1
```

Basicly you get for each `(...)` a token.